# Is it possible to use the value passed into the initiating shortcode within the add-to-wishlist.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am using a plugin along with WordPress' WooCommerce - YITH WooCommerce Wishlist Premium.

I understand how everything works and have had a high level of success using it however I have ran into a slight speed bump. I use the add-to-wishlist shortcode multiple times on the same page, once for the product the user is on (successfully). I then need to use it again on this product page within a loop, a loop of products that are 'other forms' of the product (e.g Wood would come in multiple forms: sheet, mdf, bark, chips...). I am using this shortcode to initiate the add-to-wishlist button for each 'other form':

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist product_id="' . $other_form_product_id . '"]'); ?>
```

This is being ran within a `while`, the while works beautifully.

I just need to know if it is possible to utilise this value used in the shortcode:

```
product_id="' . $other_form_product_id . '"
```

Within the add-to-wishlist.php file. As product_id is what is passed to the shortcode. I would have thought it would be something like this:

```
$post_id = $product_id;
```

It currently only uses the current products ID when each iteration of the while loop is ran, meaning I have multiple instances of the same add to wishlist button showing, not 1 of this product & multiple of other products.

**How would I be able to create a variable within the add-to-wishlist.php that is equal to the value that is passed to the wishlist shortcode?**

The question is very much solely around the control / passing of the variable in the shortcode to the file it is ran within.

**How to create a variable from a value passed through shortcode?**

If this is an obvious no, also please let me know and I will create a solution such as a dumbed down version of the product information to show on these 'other forms' tiles.

Comment: Hi Jason. A couple of posting tips if you don't mind. Stack Overflow is intended to be a collated set of questions and answers that are intended to be useful for many years to come, and thus we generally prefer technical writing to be used where possible. That means we'd rather not have thanks, signatures, and other conversational material in posts. We prefer titles to be normal flowing English, and thus homemade "tags" are discouraged (use the tag system for that).

Comment: I sometimes offer the following advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: Useful reading from the Meta Stack Overflow site: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776) See also: [Why is removing tags from the title suggested so often?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028) And finally, please have a look at [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I will rephrase my question in the morning.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I've edited it already, though you are welcome to edit further. My advice is for questions you write in the future.